# Bash printing diagonal of any size array

Tags: bash, awk

So here I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN {f=4} {printf($f" "); f=f-1}'
```

Which will take input such as:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
```

and print the diagonal that falls from upper right to bottom left.
My question is.. How can I do this for an array of ANY size? I have tried

```
 {f=NF}
```

However this resulted in: ***"awk: run time error: negative field index $-1
        FILENAME="-" FNR=2 NR=2"***

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '!i{i=NF}{printf "%s ",$i;i--}'
```

EDIT: Since Ed has already exploited all the nice and proper `awk` solutions I'll throw in a native `bash` solution:

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash

while read -ra numbers; do
        : ${i:=${#numbers[@]}}
        diag+=("${numbers[--i]}")
done < test.txt
echo "${diag[@]}"
```

.

```
$ ./t.sh
4 7 1 4
```

Comment: will add a space to the end of the output line and will not print a newline at the end of it.

Comment: Yep, like the original. Not what I would do but maybe that's what OP wants for some reason (could be used in command substitution where the trailing newline would be eaten anyway, who knows).

Comment: good point. As always, some expected output would be useful, otherwise we're trying to figure out what the output should be by reading a script that doesn't do what the OP wants :-).

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{print $(NF+1-NR)}' file    
4
7
1
4

$ awk -v ORS=" " '{print $(NF+1-NR)}' file
4 7 1 4
```

or if you want to avoid adding a space to the end of your output line and to have a terminating newline:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1?FS:""), $(NF+1-NR)} END{print ""}' file
4 7 1 4
```

Comment: That's clever, like always. If the trailing space and lack of newline doesn't matter to OP I'd just use your first example and set `ORS` to a space, that would probably be the nicest solution.

Comment: Right, I added the 2 alternatives.

Comment: +1 [g?awk master](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) strikes again!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, `NF` at `BEGIN` section is not the number of tokens on the first line. The following works:

```
awk '{if (!f) f = NF; printf($f" "); f=f-1}'
```

**Edit:** as per suggestions in the comments, a cleaner and safer way is:

```
awk '{if (!f) f = NF; printf("%s ", $f); f--}'
```

Comment: `f=f-1` can be change to `f--`

Comment: Never use printf with input data where the formatting string belongs or it'll fail when the input contains printf formatting characters like %. Use `printf "%s", $f`, not `printf $f`.

Comment: Incorporated the suggestions in the comments, thank you.

Comment: +1 for explaining the crux of the problem: that in a `BEGIN` block -- which is by definition executed _before_ any input files -- `NF` has no (meaningful) value yet (and neither do `NR`, `FNR`, `FILENAME`).