# Bash - printing diagonal line from matrix

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file like this

```
1 3 4 5 
2 5 0 9
3 4 6 6 
0 1 0 1
```

I want it to print out a diagonal line from right to left soo..

```
5 0 4 0
```

I have this so far, but its only printing out the last column.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    awk '{c=NF}{printf "%d ", $c}{c-=1}'
```

Comment: @jaypal found good example there, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
echo "1 3 4 5 
2 5 0 9
3 4 6 6 
0 1 0 1" | awk 'BEGIN{c=4}{printf("%d ", $c);c-=1}'
```

You had to put the `c=NF` part in the `BEGIN` "section". But then, `NF` is not defined yet.

So if your size is not fixed, what you could do is use `NR`:

```
echo "1 3 4 5 
2 5 0 9
3 4 6 6 
0 1 0 1" | awk '{printf("%d ", $(NF-NR+1))}'
```

See the [link in jaypal's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567581/bash-printing-diagonal-of-any-size-array) too.

Answer (score 0):

#### Printing top-left to bottom right

```
awk '{printf(" %d", $NR)}  END{print ""}'
```

Print the column corresponding to the record number; at the end, print a newline.  If you don't want the leading space:

```
awk '{printf("%s%d", pad, $NR); pad=" "}  END{print ""}'
```

#### Printing top-right to bottom left

```
awk '{if (NF >= NR) printf(" %d", $(NF - NR + 1))}  END{print ""}'
awk '{if (NF >= NR) printf("%s%d", pad, $(NF - NR + 1)); pad=" "}  END{print ""}'
```

Note that none of the programs handles malformed arrays particularly cleverly.

- GIGO — garbage in, garbage out.